# Get SQL Oracle Developer to consider the hour in LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join

I have three tables that I want to join. The first two have many records and a datetime field in the format "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS AM/PM" and the third table joins on another field and only has 16 records.

**Table A**

```
TIME_EFFECTIVE            DESCRIPTION    SOMEDATA
1998/01/11 12:00:00 AM    DescA          DataEntry
1998/01/11 11:00:00 AM    DescA          DataEntry
```

**Table B**

```
HOUR                      DESCRIPTION    SOMEDATA
1998/01/11 12:00:00 AM    DescA          DataEntry
1998/01/11 11:00:00 AM    DescA          DataEntry
```

**Table C**

```
DESCRIPTION    IMPORT
DescA          12
DescB          34
```

When I try to join the three on the following formula

```
SELECT TableA.TIME_EFFECTIVE, TableB.SOMEDATA AS SomeName, TableC.IMPORT as imp 
FROM TableA 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.TIME_EFFECTICE = TableB.HOUR
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC ON TableA.DESCRIPTION = TableC.DESCRIPTION
WHERE TIME_EFFECTIVE > '01/JAN/2017'
```

things go haywire and LEFT OUTER JOIN returns MANY more rows than are contained in the left table (TableA). I don't want this. I just want the join to match on the datetime field where the date and hour in TableA match the date and hour in TableB and on the DESCRIPTION field between TableA and TableC. I have a feeling this has something to do with the date formatting of Oracle SQL Developer, but I'm not sure. Oracle SQL developer puts it into the format "DD/MMM/YY' e.g. '01/JAN/17'. Does it even consider the time in the join, or just the date?

Comment: Could it be that you just want an inner join?

Comment: I want all from left, and then the values that match the left datetime from the right must be appended to the left.

Comment: An Oracle join on a date data type would look at both the date and the time.  It sounds like you are getting unanticipated 1 to many relationships. Perhaps you should just use sql developer's data modeler to create an erd of these tables to make sure you have the joins correct based on primary key/foreign key relationships (see here, https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/11/how-to-generate-an-erd-for-selected-tables-in-sql-developer/)

Comment: >>Oracle SQL developer puts it into the format "DD/MMM/YY' e.g. '01/JAN/17<< - that's just for display. The effective value is evaluated in full for your join. you can change your NLS_DATE_FORMAT preference to have it show the time value as well